# Differences between file.read(), file.readline() and iterating over the file object

Tags: python

I am new to computer science and am trying to create a function in python that will open files on my computer.

I know that the function `f.readline()` grabs the current line as a string, but what makes the functions `f.read()` and `for line in f:` different? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Googling it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`read(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=read#file.read) will read up to x bytes in a file.  If you don't supply the size, the entire file is read.

[`readline(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=read#file.readline) will read up to x bytes or a newline, whichever comes first. If you don't supply a size, it will read all data until it hits a newline.

When using `for line in f`, it will call the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=read#file.next) method under the hood which really just does something very similar to `readline` (although I see references that is may do some buffering more efficiently since iterating usually means you are planning to read the entire file).

There is also `readlines()` which reads all lines into memory.

Comment: Obligatory Python Docs ref: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects