# why "for line in file" is more memory efficient than "readline()"?

Tags: python, file-io

[As is written in python docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVXcq.png)

[See also the original python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between file.read(), file.readline() and iterating over the file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313440/differences-between-file-read-file-readline-and-iterating-over-the-file-obj)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.